# Form Submit Iterating for Existing Username React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, forms, submit

I'm trying to create a sign up page where it first iterates through existing accounts and submits when input account is available; otherwise, it returns an error message if just one element matches.

I first tried .map, but it iterates through the entire array and still submits if one value is false.  I then tried .find, but still produces the same result.  Afterwards, I tried switch, case and could only return the proper outcome with ==.  Lastly, I tried .find and .map using .includes but, again, no luck.

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    accounts.find(acc => {
    if (acc.username.includes(formData.username)) {
        console.log("taken");
    } else {
    some post request code
}
```

How can I create a function that only produces one outcome if one of many elements meets the condition?  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the function that finds or filters the username to a variable and then create an if statement using that variable.

To return the first matching object in the array of accounts

```
const matchingAccount = accounts.find(account => account.username.includes(formData.username);
```

To return an array of matching account objects

```
const matchingAccounts = accounts.filter(account => account.username.includes(formData.username);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I solved my own question shortly after submitting the post and used .some method, but assigning it to a variable is what I also did.  I'll keep your answer in mind though.  Thanks again